# Automatically pass variable to any view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm on Laravel 5.3. I can just pass variable to view by

```
public function test(){
    $testVar = 'test';

    return view('pages.home',compact('testVar'));
}
```

How can I automatically pass a variable to view without creating the variable unto the controller and then pass it to the compact argument? like

```
public function test(){
    return view('pages.home');
}
```

and then in view, I can just retrieved the variable anywhere in my application, like using the 'Auth::check()'

```
<div class="menu" id="primary-menu">
    {{ $menu }}
</div>
```

any ideas, help please?